# Mapping column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-mapping

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkV8q.png)I have created 3 data frames from a JSON file.
I'm trying to create a column on my working data frame by mapping the key column to the other 2 data frames, the method I use works, but it throws up a warning "*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*.
How do I go around this?

Error image

[image: 1]

Comment: At some point _before_ this provided code you have unsafely subset your DataFrame. Either `fpl_df = df[cols]` or `fpl_df = df[mask]` when it should have been `fpl_df = df[cols].copy()` or `fpl_df = df[mask].copy()` The warning is letting you know that `df[mask]['col'] = value` may not work because `df[mask]` may produce a copy and recommends that you use `df.loc[mask, 'col'] = value` but that message is not clear here since you're doing something like `fpl_df = df[mask]` then later doing `fpl_df[col] = value` which looks to pandas like a (deferred) `df[mask][col] = value` call.

Comment: So you can either [suppress the warning](/a/53954986/15497888) if it's not causing issues, or you can [fix the problem](/a/66362915/15497888) by making it an explicit copy.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to join the dataframes.

if you are just bothered by warning messages and if you don't like to see them, you can suppress them by the following code

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).